# remove_const and module's name

Tags: ruby, module, constants

In [standard Ruby documentation for `remove_const`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_const), I noticed this line:

> If that constant referred to a module, this will not change that
>   module's name and can lead to confusion.

What does this mean? What does removing/unloading a constant have to do with module names? What kind of confusion is this referring to?

Comment: Module names are constants.

Answer (score 5):

When a module is defined with a name `A`,

```
module A; end
a = A
```

then its name is `"A"`, so you can call it as `A` (by it's name):

```
a.name # => "A"
A # => A
```

But if you undefine `A`:

```
self.class.send(:remove_const, :A)
```

then you cannot call `A` anymore:

```
A # >> NameError: uninitialized constant A
```

but its name remains as `"A"`:

```
a.name # => "A"
a # => A
```

That is probably what is meant by confusing.

Comment: What will happen if `A` is defined as `module A; def self.foo; puts "foo"; end; end;` and `a.foo` is called _after_ `remov_const` is called?

Comment: It will print `"foo"`, just as you expected.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that `A` was **not** removed/unloaded? Does `a=A` create a copy of the entire module definition?

Comment: No, `A` was removed. What it had pointed to was not removed. `a = A` does not create a copy.

Answer (score 3):

A module's name is automatically set when the module is assigned to a constant for the very first time. But, it does not get automatically *unset* when the module is un-assigned. This may be confusing.

See:

```
a = Module.new
a.name    #=> nil
a.to_s    #=> '#<Module:0x00007f91b38625f8>'
a.inspect #=> '#<Module:0x00007f91b38625f8>'

A = a
a.name    #=> 'A'
a.to_s    #=> 'A'
a.inspect #=> 'A'

B = a
B.name    #=> 'A'
B.to_s    #=> 'A'
B.inspect #=> 'A'

self.class.send(:remove_const, :A)
a = nil
B.name    #=> 'A'
B.to_s    #=> 'A'
B.inspect #=> 'A'
```

Now, you can only refer to the module via the constant `B`, but the name of the module is still `A`, which is the first constant that it was ever assigned to. Removing the constant will not change and/or delete the module's name.